# how to make Drawing over an image in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

In this case I want to make drawing image.
I want to save the results image in public folder in laravel, How can I store the image results in php laravel?

This is my code, only with javascript, how can I get data image (the results) from javascript to controller php.

Html:

```html
<h1>
  Draw over image
</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/jnW4Qz/Grumpy_Cat_920x584.jpg" width=400 height=200 />
  <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="save">Save</button>
  <button id="clear">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```js
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/szimek/d6a78gwq/embed/"></script>
<script>
  
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
  penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
});
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');
var cancelButton = document.getElementById('clear');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');

// Send data to server instead...
  window.open(data);
});

cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  signaturePad.clear();
});

</script>
```

Css:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.signature-pad {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to draw over the cat picture in `.wrapper` and save both as one image?